# Finding upper and lower bounds using Chebycheff inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Our tutor told us that using Chebycheff inequality (CI), i.e. $P(|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|>\epsilon)\leq \frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\epsilon^2}$, where $\epsilon >0$, allows us to find upper and lower bounds in all situations if we use "clever" manipulations of inequalities. She came up with some examples  to explain her statement and I didn't question it...

---

Now, I constructed a few exapmples on my own which lead to some confusion.

Let's consider a random variable $X$, $0<a<\mathbb{E}(X)<b$ and $\mathbb{V}(X)\geq0$.

---

1.) Find an $L\geq 0$ such that $P(X>a)\geq L$. This is equivalent to $P(X\leq a)\leq 1-L$,
$$
\begin{align*}
&P(X\leq a)=P(X-\mathbb{E}(X)\leq a -\mathbb{E}(X))=P(X-\mathbb{E}(X)\leq -|a -\mathbb{E}(X)|)\\
&=P(\mathbb{E}(X)-X\geq |a -\mathbb{E}(X)|)\leq \frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{(a -\mathbb{E}(X))^2}=:1-L\\
&\implies L= 1-\frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{(a -\mathbb{E}(X))^2}.
\end{align*}$$
O.k. no problem, in this case it might be that $L$ is better than $0$.

2.) Find an $U\leq 1$ such that $P(X>a)\leq U$,
$$
\begin{align*}
&P(X>a)=P(X-\mathbb{E}(X)> a -\mathbb{E}(X))=P(X-\mathbb{E}(X)> -|a -\mathbb{E}(X)|)\\
&=P(\mathbb{E}(X)-X< |a -\mathbb{E}(X)|)\leq???
\end{align*}$$
In this case it seems that we can't find a better bound using Chebycheff, right?

3.) Find an $U\leq 1$ such that $P(X<a)\leq U$,
$$
\begin{align*}
&P(X<a)=P(X-\mathbb{E}(X)< a -\mathbb{E}(X))=P(X-\mathbb{E}(X)< -|a -\mathbb{E}(X)|)\\
&=P(\mathbb{E}(X)-X> |a -\mathbb{E}(X)|)\leq\frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{(a -\mathbb{E}(X))^2}=:U.
\end{align*}$$
In this case we find an upper bound that can be better than $1$.

4.) Find an $L\geq 0$ such that $P(X<a)\geq U$. This is equivalent to $P(X\geq a)\leq 1-U$,
$$
\begin{align*}
&P(X\geq a)=P(X-\mathbb{E}(X)\geq a -\mathbb{E}(X))=P(X-\mathbb{E}(X)\geq -|a -\mathbb{E}(X)|)\\
&=P(\mathbb{E}(X)-X\leq |a -\mathbb{E}(X)|)\leq ???
\end{align*}$$
In this case it seems that we can't find a better bound using Chebycheff, right?

---

If I look at $P(X>b)$ and $P(X<b)$ I run into the same problems. So I doubt that Chebycheff inequality helps us to find a better bound in each case. Am I right or are there some magic manipulations that produce bounds in case 2.) and 4.)?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio, why does this matter? For example: $$
P(\mathbb{E}(X)-X\geq |a -\mathbb{E}(X)|)\leq P(|\mathbb{E}(X)-X|\geq |a -\mathbb{E}(X)|)\leq \frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{(a -\mathbb{E}(X))^2}
$$ I applied Chebychev's inequality because $|a -\mathbb{E}(X)|>0$

Comment: You're right-will delete my last comment

Comment: Basically you are trying to find lower bounds for tail probabilities. This might be related https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/a-lower-bound-for-the-tail-probability-of-a-normal-distribution/; See also https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375807000213

Comment: But I do agree that "in general" we cannot have nontrivial bounds

Comment: Lower bound for probability of an event gives upper bound for probability of the complement event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your tutor meant that inequality for the event $|X-E[x]|\geq\varepsilon$
$$P(|X-E[x]|\geq\varepsilon)\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\varepsilon^2}$$
can be rewritten as inequality for the complement event $|X-E[x]|<\varepsilon$
$$P(|X-E[x]|<\varepsilon)\geq 1-\frac{\sigma^2}{\varepsilon^2}$$